# Is it possible to make an uber-like map tracking using PubNub?

Tags: geolocation, tracking, pubnub

I have been trying to make a web app that has a certain feature like uber where users can see other users on a map. I read about pubNub (https://www.pubnub.com/) and I saw they have a tutorial that allows you to track movements on a map https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/javascript/mapping-javascript-tracking/.

They also provide a tool called presence (https://www.pubnub.com/products/presence/) which allows you to see if users have joined your web session or not. I would like to, with presence, to show on a map if people have joined the session or left the session. If they are on the map, I would like the movements to be updated as well.

I am just wondering if someone has used pubNub before to achieve something similar and if so how to go about it?

Answer (score 3):

## Clone Uber with PubNub and EON Maps

> https://github.com/pubnub/pubnUber - GitHub Repository

[image: PubNub Uber App]

Today we're going to use Phonegap and PubNub to create a simple taxi hailing app. What we'll walk through today is the same technology stack used by Uber, Gett, and other taxi hailing apps. They all work in a similar fashion.

### Getting started

1. Install [phonegap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap) on the CLI.
2. Clone this repository locally.
3. The repo contains two directories `/rider` and `/driver`. We're going to start with `/driver`.

#### Set Up PubNub

First, we need to set up PubNub. the `PUBNUB` variables comes for free from the EON library. The `publish_key` and `subscribe_key` settings come from your [PubNub account](http://pubnub.com).

```
var channel = "pubnub-taxi-app";

var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key: 'demo',
    subscribe_key: 'demo'
});
```

The `pubnub` plugs the same `pubnub` variable we configured in the first step into EON. This lets us use our own PubNub keys within EON.

Our Mapbox configuration is set and we're ready to send some

### Publish messages to the channel

Define our PubNub channel.

Subscribe.

```
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: channel,
    message: function(message,env,channel){

        if(message == 'hail') {

            var pickup = confirm("Someone requested a ride!", "Accept");

            if(pickup) {

                pubnub.publish({
                    channel: channel,
                    message: 'pickup'
                });

            }

        }
    }    
});
```

And here is the `hail()` function.

```
var hail = function(argument) {

    pubnub.publish({
        channel: channel,
        message: 'hail'
    });

    alert('Waiting for driver...');

};
```

Comment: thanks so much for replying. I am building my application with Angular2 for now. Is there an example using this with that or will this work with Angular?

Comment: Both frameworks will work as you need.  You'll best find a good starting point here: https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/map/bus/ - then you can directly use Angular2 or 1 or 4.  And not Angular3, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Also note that the sample code is PubNub JS SDK v3. I am in the process of upgrading it to be v4x. The EON code is also older code and needs to be upgraded which I am also doing.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Craig.  As of today, this is true.  Good to note.